# Добавить listener в контроллер для ожидания реакции пользователя

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, ontouchlistener

Есть rest контроллер который принимает метод POST от пользоввателя с сущностью которая описывает режим работы устройства.

Далее эта сущность или сохраняется в репозитории или перетирает существующий режим.

Пока все происходит чисто в бек и тестирую я через postman. Никакого фронта нет.

Я бы хотел добавить такую логику. Вывести пользователю при обращении в метод POST такой ответ "вы действительно хотите перезаписать существующий режим, если да пришлите true"

соответсвенно далее пользователь отправляет "true" на getStatusOperation(String answer)
и только тогда, я уже сохраняю новый режим работы в репозитории. А пока пользователь не ответит метод контроллера будет висеть и ждать.

Как реализовать такой слушатель, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я бы копал в сторону HATEOAS, но детально подсказать не смогу)

Comment: В чем проблема? Отправте сперва с фронта запрос, есть ли режим с таким id (либо другим уникальным полем). Если есть выводите уведомление, если нет - отправляете post запрос и сохраняете в базу.

Comment: Думаю это крайне плохая идея, заставлять метод контроллера висеть и ждать. Тут возникает сразу вопросы вроде: сколько ждать? что делать если ответа так и не было? Да и просто представить, что это большое приложение и зависает тысячи потоков.... Это все большие расходы, хотя возможно в чем-то я ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задержки делать не надо. Попробуйте сделать так:

1. Метод принимает данные + флаг `forceUpdate`
2. Если данных в БД нет или клиент прислал `forceUpdate=true` - пишет их и возвращает код 200.
3. Если данные уже есть и в запросе нет флага `forceUpdate=true` - возвращает 409 код (conflict).
4. Клиент, если видит 409 код - отправляет данные с флагом `forceUpdate=true`

Comment: отлично. и ждать не нужно и методы rest между собой не связаны никак а это важно. спасибо!